# "..allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level" error on deploying the website on web host

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, web, web-config

I came across the solution of this genetic problem all across the internet and Stackoverflow, but none of them talk about the same after/on **deployment**. I also read this famous [article](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/02/17/163375.aspx) . So, my website runs absolutely fine via VS 2010. However, I get this problem the moment I deploy my **website** using the copy tool of VS 2010.

There are three `web.config` files in. `1- root, 2- Users folder, 3- accounts folder`. The  tag exists in the web.config file in the root. The hierarchy of which looks like: `domain.com / httpdocs / websitefolder / web.config`. In the `websitefolder` there are `Accounts` and `Users` folders which further contain web.configs, but non of them have the  tag.

What could possibly go wrong from the development machine to deployment? The error I am getting is on line:

```
Line 16:  <authentication mode="Forms">
```

In the httpdocs, there are **other** projects with web.configs, can that be a problem? In that case, I also deleted their contents, but didn't help (but may be I should have done a better job? I don't know if this is what was required at all?).

Also, this is a **website**, so there's **no** bin or obj folder being created, none of that kind of issue. Please suggest, I am not able to figure out the problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you have multiple sites in sub directories of one site, inspite you delete a web.config, the problem will persist. In that case even the sub folders should be marked as an application.

Is the folder in which you have this website deployed an application in IIS? It is one main reason why this error could occur.

If its not, make it as an application and the problem should resolve.

**Update:** Seems you have used File System while developing your website.

Firstly install IIS server like "[this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-install-iis-on-windows-vista/)".

Next you should create a virtual directory in IIS. See "[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" . (in physical path, select the path upto your deployment folder)

Now run the website. If your problem is solved it means the issue is with the virtual directory in your remote server. So report them.

Comment: @dev Let me know if this is not the issue.

Comment: thanks for help. Can you please tell me how do I know whether its an application in IIS or not? Also, its a website and NOT a web application. Also, when you say "make it as an application", how do I do that? sorry for several questions, but can you please describe whatever you just stated? Right now its beyond my comprehension. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. But first let me know do you have the folder in which you deployed your website in the virtual directory of IIS?

Comment: I am so sorry, but how do I know that? Do I need to ask my webhosting company? I am on HostGator.

Comment: Oh so you are not testing/dint test your site in a local server(IIS)?

Comment: Do you have a IIS server installed in your system? And what location have you chosen for you site? local system or HTTP? I cant solve your problem unless you tell me these

Comment: I totally did, its running great via VS 2010 on Windows 7. I just press F5, and the ASP.NET Development Server creates a new port to run the website. I don't think its IIS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16465/discussion-between-dev-dreamer-and-cdeez)

Comment: unfortunately, the StackOverflow chat isn't working. It loads and then dies. Is it working for you?

Comment: yupp. Iam on the page. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16465/discussion-between-dev-dreamer-and-cdeez

Comment: not working for me :(, can you please suggest me here? or I can come online on any preferred chat service you use?

Comment: Look at my update. Quickly learn installing IIS and creating virtual directories

Comment: I installed IIS7, now the same problem is seen on my computer. What's next? Thanks.