# “allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level” error on after deployment (following up)

Tags: asp.net, .net, deployment, exception, web-config

This is a follow up question to the [one I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338559/allowdefinition-machinetoapplication-beyond-application-level-error-on-dep/). I got a reply and implemented the same but no luck. I am totally not able to understand where I am going wrong, and why isn't it working. Can someone please help me? It's working locally via ASP.NET Web Development Server, but not via IIS (locally or when trying to deploy). Also, why does server matter so much?

Please note that its  a website, and not a web application. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your application is targeted to .NET 4.0 while app pool to .NET 2.0.

Comment: thanks for help. Yes, its targeted to .NET 4.0. So what shall I do? change it to .NET 2.0 in the web.config file? Also, I have another simple website WITHOUT authentication stuff targeted to .NET 4.0, and that one works just fine. So can this be an issue? thanks.

Comment: @DevDreamer: Do both apps use same app pool? Configure app pool to use .NET 4.0